# Get flex component id using Mouse event action

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

In flex application how to get the ID of specific display component using mouse event. For example if I want to get the ID of a button it should be displayed when I click the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do it with `event.currentTarget.id` like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            protected function niceButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show(" the button id is: "+event.currentTarget.id)

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center">
        <s:Button id="niceButton" label="click me" click="niceButton_clickHandler(event)" />
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Application>
```